# Android Studio Flutter UI Guides don't work

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

[image: Android Studio 3.4.2]This may be a silly question but i do not see the flutter UI Guides. I checked the "Emphasize widgets with multiple children" and all plugins are installed and activated. I am using version 3.4.2 .

Is this an error in Android Studio or just a silly mistake?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed with the flutter plugin-update 38.2

Answer (score 0):

This is what is is happening on my Android Studio (3.4)

Before

[image]

[image]

After

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same settings but the UI Guides are not visible.